# Asyn. LinkButton with controller

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a updatePanel with a LinkButton and in the LinkButton are some Controller.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateRepTrack" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdateRepTrack" DynamicLayout="true">

                    ....

        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <ItemTemplate>

          ....

          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Literal  ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
               </asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>

          ....

       </ItemTemplate>
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now when I click on the Text(Label) the page do a Full Postback, but when I click next to the Text(on the Link directly) then the page do an asynchronous postback.
Can me help someone with a solution so that I get asynchronous postback everywhere.

Thanks.

Solution I have tried

I have tried to add this code behinde

```
       With CType(e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1"), LinkButton)
            Dim trigger As New AsyncPostBackTrigger
            trigger.ControlID = .UniqueID
            UpdateRepTrack.Triggers.Add(trigger)
        End With
```

Comment: What is an "asynchronous postback"?

Comment: Show your `UpdatePanel`. Have you tried to add an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`? Why do you need to nest the label in the `LinkButton` at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278891/asynchronous-and-synchronous-postback-in-asp-net

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter Jeah I have try to add this code behinde with a AsyncPostBackTrigger. This is a very large btn with some Text and List items.

Comment: @HustlaSmiley-.-: then show what you've tried. Also, as mentioned it would be helpful to see the UpdatePanel. If it contains more controls you could replace the rest with `....` to keep it simple

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter Okay I had edit the code. I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. When you add the "clientIDMode" attribute to the linkbutton it works fine.

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="LinkButton1" clientIDMode="AutoID" runat="server">
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Literal  ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have tried a little round with a clear page. Then I have removed the repeater and it works. After this I found this page 
[Leonid's space](https://leonidius2010.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/linkbutton-inside-repeater-inside-updatepanel/)  and this was the solution.