# Different newline from multiline asp:TextBox on full postback vs. async postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, newline, postback

I have **TextBox** in **MultiLine** mode. **Text** property contains some newlines (\r\n).

Why there is a difference between data returned to server on *full postback* — "\r\n" is returned and on *async postback* — "\n" is returned?

User agent: IE, Firefox, Edge, Chrome

---

**aspx:**

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbText" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200px" />

            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lDump" /><br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAsync" Text="Async postback" />

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFull" Text="Full postback" />
```

**aspx.cs:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAsync.Click += Dump;
        btnFull.Click += Dump;

        if (!IsPostBack)
            tbText.Text = "Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3";
    }

    private void Dump(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lDump.Text = tbText.Text.Replace("\r", "[CR]").Replace("\n", "[LF]");
    }
```

**output:**

- Async postback: *Line1[LF]Line2[LF]Line3*
- Full postback: *Line1[CR][LF]Line2[CR][LF]Line3*

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is by design if you're using Firefox/Chrome or other browsers which use Unix-like `LF` (`0x0A` in ASCII) as line ending, as noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328):

> The most common difference (and probably the only one worth worrying
>   about) is **lines end with CRLF on Windows, NL (LF) on Unix-likes**, and CR on
>   older Macs (the situation has changed with OS X to be like Unix). Note
>   the shift in meaning from LF to NL, for the exact same character,
>   gives the differences between Windows and Unix.

However in IE which uses Windows-style line ending (`CRLF`/ `0x0D0A` in ASCII), the same async postback returns desired result, as shown in image below:

[image: CRLF in IE vs other browsers]

The reason behind different behavior presented is in standard postback, `textarea` produced by multiline `TextBox` control sends its content to the server using complete `POST` method, and follows Windows-style line ending in server-side process. However in asynchronous postback, only contents of `UpdatePanel` updated with browser-dependent AJAX requests.

Craig Wardman confirmed this behavior in browsers using Unix-like line endings, and proposed a solution to standardize usage of `CRLF` for both synchronous and asynchronous postback in server side with `Regex.Replace` (see references section).

> On a synchronous postback it seems ASP.NET fixes this and you will get
>   CrLf in your text on the server. **However, when you are posting back
>   asynchronously using AJAX, you only get Lf in your text when Firefox
>   is used.**

References:

[Asynchronous and synchronous postback in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278891/asynchronous-and-synchronous-postback-in-asp-net)

[Textbox CrLf in Firefox using AJAX UpdatePanel](http://www.craigwardman.com/Blogging/BlogEntry/textbox-crlf-in-firefox-using-ajax-updatepanel)